# Does a fuzzy matching mode exist for the zsh shell?

Tags: zsh, autocomplete

I've recently fallen in love with efficient text completion systems. One of my favourite kinds of completion is so-called fuzzy completion.
This is a mode where the program will complete the user's input based on only a couple of characters that can occur 'anywhere' (almost) in the file name or path. This feature exists at least for these programs:

- TextMate
- Vim Command-T plugin https://github.com/wincent/Command-T
- Vim completion system https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache
- Various modern IDEs

Usage example of this mode in a text editor:

User is trying to complete the word longWordNameThatTheyDontWantToWriteByHand, and they can do so by typing e.g. the first letter and some of the capital case letters. So typing **lwnt** could complete to the whole word.

My question is: is there a mode or something similar that I could use with the zsh shell?

Answer (score 42):

I have this in my `.zshrc`

```bsh
# 0 -- vanilla completion (abc => abc)
# 1 -- smart case completion (abc => Abc)
# 2 -- word flex completion (abc => A-big-Car)
# 3 -- full flex completion (abc => ABraCadabra)
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' \
  'm:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}' \
  'r:[^[:alpha:]]||[[:alpha:]]=** r:|=* m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}' \
  'r:|?=** m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}'
```

It adds full fuzzy matching to `zsh`'s completion engine. It lacks the super smarts of sublime text, but, yes, it will complete `lwnt -> longWordNameThatTheyDontWantToWriteByHand`.

Comment: I just found a bug: doesn't work for filenames with spaces, given you're typing anything after the space ☹ I.e. `stack install && vlc ~/Music/erf` doesn't complete to `stack install && vlc ~/Music/FGFC820\ -\ Perfect\ War.mp3`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel hey, thanks for bumping this. I actually use `'r:|?=** m:{a-z\-}={A-Z\_}'` now, which is a bunch simpler, and doesn't suffer from the problem you describe.

Comment: That's great! Maybe you could make a plugin with this code. Just so that it's easier to find.

Comment: This just doesn't work. Doens't do anything

Comment: I can confirm this works fine.  @PyhonNut, maybe you should make it extra clear that you edited the answer to fix Hi-Angel's bug.  Thank for this sweet snippet!

Comment: There is now a plugin that does this for you: https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete

Answer (score 18):

Check out my project [fzf](https://github.com/junegunn/fzf).

It's a general purpose fuzzy finder written in Golang that can be used with any list of things: files, processes, command history, git branches, etc.

For zsh, it provide the following key bindings:

- `CTRL-T` - Paste the selected file path(s) into the command line
- `CTRL-R` - Paste the selected command from history into the command line
- `ALT-C` - cd into the selected directory

and fuzzy completion mode:

```
# Files under current directory
# - You can select multiple items with TAB key
vim **<TAB>

# Files under parent directory
vim ../**<TAB>

# Files under parent directory that match `fzf`
vim ../fzf**<TAB>

# Files under your home directory
vim ~/**<TAB>

# Directories under current directory (single-selection)
cd **<TAB>

# Directories under ~/github that match `fzf`
cd ~/github/fzf**<TAB>

# Process IDs. Can select multiple processes with TAB or Shift-TAB
kill -9 <TAB>

# Host names
ssh **<TAB>
telnet **<TAB>

# Environment variables / aliases
unset **<TAB>
export **<TAB>
unalias **<TAB>
```

Comment: How can I make it tab complete with this by default? Without having to type `**`

Comment: @theonlygusti Search for `fzf tab zsh github`.